# Creating a nav bar with flexbox

Tags: html, css, frontend, navbar, nav

I've been learning code only for a couple of weeks, so I have a very basic knowledge.
I got stuck trying to build a navbar using flexbox.

For some reason I can't get my nav buttons (

) to stand in a horizontal way.
I've been trying and rewritting my code, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the link to my code: https://codepen.io/kokazp/pen/xxORovj?editors=1100

Thanks in advance.

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    background-color: lightGray;
}

navbar {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px var(--clr-gray200);
    padding: 1rem 0;
    border-radius: var(--radius);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }

#header-img{
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
    
li, a{
    background-color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px;
    color:black;
}
        
li a:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel=StyleSheet HREF="estilo.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <header id="header">
            <navbar id="nav-bar">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/craft-brewery-logos/1.jpg" id="header-img" alt="Company logo"></li>
                    <li><a href="#form">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#beers">Beers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#video">Video</a></li>
                </ul>
            </navbar>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

let's make it clear when you use a flex-box it applies to children not to grand children, when you apply `display:flex` to ur navbar it will make the **ul** a flex child, so **li tags** are not flex, secondly you're making it columns so it will make it in a vertical way.
solution: you can make the ul

```
ul{display:flex;}
```

and it will make the li go to row direction by default